# Bad result in saving SVG if Illustration is complex

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, 3d, save, shadows

If I save an SVG of an Illustrator graphic it is unsatisfying. How can I save SVG files with complex graphics with shading and 3D effects?

[image: EPS file in Illustrator]
[image: SVG output]

Comment: Reduce the complexity, at least in the overall construction.

Comment: SVG doesn't support all Illustrator's effects. You should construct your file without them. If you reveal the current construction of the 3D-like items someone may show workarounds. One way is to rasterize in high resolution under YOUR control, but I guess you expect something less brutal. What SVG version export you tried?

Comment: If you need an svg output, I recommend to achieve all the job in Inkscape. Illustrator and Corell svgs can display weired on the browser in dependance of the effects and complexity of the graphic.